# Space between Lyrics and Stave, no paper effect related to remove "Bar_engraver"

Tags: lilypond

Using modern gregorian notation, I remove the bar engraver, but that causes that the space between Lyrics and next Stave shrinks.  I want to increase the space between the Lyrics and next stave but the paper settings as suggested in other discussion has no effect **system-system-spacing** basic-distance and **score-system-spacing** I tried also verticalaxisgroup in layout, with no luck. Any workaround?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[program={C:/apps/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe},debug=true,nofragment]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}
    \medskip
    \begin{lilypond}
        \include "gregorian.ly"
    musicOne = \relative {
        \autoBeamOff
        g'8 \ictus g8 g8 \ictus g8 g4 e8 f8 \ictus g8 e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 g8 \ictus g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis
        %%2
        g8 g8 \ictus g8 g4 e8 f8\ictus g8 e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 \ictus g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis \break
        %%3
        g8 \ictus g8 g8 \ictus g4 e8 \ictus f8 g8 \ictus e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 \ictus g8 g8 \ictus g8 g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis \break
        %%4
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 \ictus e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 e8 \ictus g8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis \break
        %%5
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 \ictus e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 e8\ictus f8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis \break
        %%6
        g8 g8 \ictus g8 g4 e8 \ictus f8 g8\ictus e8 d4 \divisioMaior
        g8 g8 g8 g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 \ictus e8 d4 \divisioMaior \break
        g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 g8 e8 \ictus f8 g8 [f8 e8 \ictus f8] g4 \finalis
        %%
    }

    verseOne = \lyricmode {
        A -- NI  -- MA Chri -- sti, sanc -- tí -- fi -- ca me: 
        Cór -- pus Chrí -- sti, sal -- va __ me.
        
        Sán -- guis Chrí -- sti, in -- é -- bri -- a me:
        A -- qua lá -- te -- ris Chrí -- sti, lá -- va __ me.
        
        Pá -- ssi -- o Chrí -- sti, con -- fór -- ta me:
        O bó -- ne Jé -- su, e -- xáu -- di __ me.
        
        In -- tra tú -- a vúl -- ne -- ra abs -- cón -- de me:
        Ne per -- mít -- tas me se -- pa -- rá -- ri a __ te.
        
        Ab hos -- te ma -- líg -- no de -- fén -- de me:
        In hó -- ra mor -- tis me -- ae vó -- ca __ me.
        
        Et iú -- be me ve -- ní -- re ad te: 
        ut cum Sán -- ctis tú -- is láu -- dem te
        in saé -- cu -- la sæ -- cu -- ló -- rum.
        A __ men
        %%3
    }

\score {
    <<
    \new Voice = "one" {
        \musicOne
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
        \verseOne
    }
    >>
}
\paper {
    system-system-spacing #'basic-distance = #20
    score-system-spacing =
    #'((basic-distance . 20)
    (minimum-distance . 6)
    (padding . 1)
    (stretchability . 12))
}

\layout {
    \context {
        \Staff
        \remove "Bar_engraver" % <<--- Problem with this
        \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
    }
}
    \end{lilypond}
    \medskip 
%   End of document.
\end{document}
```

[image: without bar engraver]

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Knute’s remark on the wrong syntax for setting basic-distance this cannot work! That is because lyluatex needs to hand over the page breaking to LuaTeX. This is done by rendering each single system into a separate file and then arranging these systems on the page. This then allows LuaTeX to insert page breaks between such systems as it sees fit.

This means that to get such settings to work you must specify them from LuaLaTeX. You could either simply specify the line spacing by doing something `\linespread{5}\selectfont` before the Lilypond block, which will tell LuaTeX to put more space between these systems, or you can use the hook `\betweenLilyPondSystem` to do something like `\newcommand{\betweenLilyPondSystem}[1]{\vspace{2em}\linebreak}`.

If you want to include a complex layout with page geometry or multiple pages or something you can tell lyluatex to insert a page instead by adding the option `insert=fullpage` (so you’d do `\begin{lilypond}[insert=...] ...`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for understanding it was related to lyluatex.  I did not know about the logic of lyluatex to hand over the page breaking to LuaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried your LilyPond source code, I assumed a version of 2.22.2, but even with lower versions your syntax for system-system-spacing is wrong.  I tried this:

```
system-system-spacing.basic-distance = 20
```

...and the space between systems was very large.

Also, be sure when you post code that it engraves without any problems.  Your code has some syntax for a document that is not LilyPond and causes errors.

Comment: The fact I showed an output indicates that in my sytem (Texstudio, built utput  with Lulatex) there was no complaint.  Please do not assume I posted a syntax that does not compile. Thus, in Texstudio, Lulatex the  system-system-spacing.basic-distance = 20 fails to do anything.  My apologies for not clarifying under the circumstances the code has no effect